# Easy way to find if directional derivatives exist at $x \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Say I have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$, given by 
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{x^{2}y}{x^{4} + y^{2}}
$$for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and we set $f(0) = 0$. It can be shown that this function has all directional derivatives at $(0,0)$ but is not even continuous.

However, what if I want to show that directional derivatives exist at a point $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$? One way would be to compute
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+ah, y + bh) - f(x,y)}{h}
$$
which is an extremely tedious computation. Is this the way to generally show all directional derivatives exist; straight from definition?

An alternative way would be the following: I compute partial derivatives at some non-zero point $(x,y)$, and show that those are continuous in a neighborhood of that point. My question: are "nice" looking functions in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ continuous generally? If the partial derivative of this function w.r.t. $x$ is 
$$
\frac{2xy}{x^{4} + y^{2}} - \frac{x^{2}y}{(x^{4} + y^{2})^{2}}4x^{3}
$$
Can I just say that this function is continuous at some $(x,y) \neq 0$ without looking further into it, simply because it looks "nice"?

Overall: what is the usual way to show that a function has directional derivatives at points which are not the origin? The limit computation isn't easy in any of these cases.

Comment: The following are useful: Products and sums of differentiable functions are differentiable, also, quotients of differentiable functions are differentiable if the denominator stays away from $0$

Answer (score 0):

At a point $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, we ave$$\nabla f(x,y)=\left(\frac{2 y \left(x y^2-x^5\right)}{\left(x^4+y^2\right)^2},\frac{x^2 \left(x^4-y^2\right)}{\left(x^4+y^2\right)^2}\right)$$and therefore the directional derivative at $(x,y)$ with respect to the direction $(a,b)$ is$$\nabla f(x,y).(a,b)=\frac{2 y \left(x y^2-x^5\right)}{\left(x^4+y^2\right)^2}a+\frac{x^2 \left(x^4-y^2\right)}{\left(x^4+y^2\right)^2}b.$$

Comment: This is only true where $f$ is differentiable though right? My question was more to prove the existence of directional derivatives, which is anyway guaranteed by differentiability.

Comment: Yes, my answer uses the fact that $f$ is differentiable outside $(0,0)$. That's what happens for most functions with partial derivatives anyway.